# Image Produces top border line

Tags: html, css

I have a li tag that when it's hovered over with the mouse the background image url is set to a dark brown arrow as seen in this image below.

[image]

As you can see, a black line is produced on the top right of the image. I have no idea how this is produced and I want the dark line removed. How do I fix it?

The CSS:

```
#topcol1navtall ul.contactsleftnav li.dash.selected {

    background:#7c6a54 image-url('contact-arrow-nav.png') right no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #f17ca6;
    margin-top: 5px; padding-top: 8px;

}
```

The HTML:

```
<li class="contact">
  <div class="text">
    <span class="name">
      <!-- / Dynamically loads edit form into right column -->
      <a href="/contacts/6/edit" data-remote="true">asdf, Billy 3 </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Post the relevant `HTML` code.

Comment: try adding `border-style:none` to css

Comment: And you are sure it is not in your image?

Comment: Can u also add a jsfiddle.net demo demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Agree with @putvande, it seems likely that the black line is on the image itself.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/U6vdQ/ Post relevant CSS + HTML, please.

Comment: with this piece of code nothing is clear. I am sure image is okay. try to use `border:none` on `:hover`.

Comment: Why are you sure it is not the image? It looks like the 'border' is only on the top, nowhere else.

Comment: `border-style:none` and 'border:none' does nothing. I checked the image itself and I see no top black line.

Comment: If I received a negative vote, can you explain why? I've posted the relevant html and css. I was testing answers posted before creating a jsfiddle and now I found the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line isn't black. It's the same color as your background, #7c6a54. Your image is either transparent in the first row of pixels, or it's one pixel too short and somehow anchored to the bottom of the containing li.

I would guess it's probably the latter. Your li is one pixel taller than the background image you're using. I would recommend making your background image taller than you need it be and then explicitly anchoring it either to the top or bottom of the containing element like so:
`background: #7c6a54 image-url(your-url) right top no-repeat;`. Then make the background image taller by a few pixels. Make sure the bottom angle doesn't suddenly turn into a vertical line or else you'll have a weird one-pixel bump there. Actually continue the angle so that you retain a smooth line on that end.

The other option is to explicitly declare the height of the li (making adjustments for your padding), but then you run into trouble if someone's browser renders text larger than you expect it to. If you're going to explicitly declare the height of the li, you should also explicitly declare the font-size and line-height of the text in the li (or they should inherit that from a parent element, but don't leave it to chance).

Comment: That did it. The li was too high so I adjusted the height. Thanks!